# bcp export to Excel generates unreadable data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2 and I'm trying to export data from a view with bcp called from the command line.

The command that I'm using is

`bcp "SELECT * FROM dbo.products_view_feed" queryout C:\excelExport.xls -w -U ** -P **`

and my problem is that when I try to open the Excel file I get an error saying that:

`The file you are trying to open, 'excelExport.xls', is in a different format than specified by the extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source.`

After pressing `Yes` in this window the Excel file is opened and data is readable, but only a part of it. The rest of it is unreadable (special characters and alpha-numeric characters altogether).

And the data is not necessarily unreadable from a point on, but parts of it (multiple columns, can't identify exactly if only a few or more).

I don't know what to try and change for the data file not to be created corrupted so the file would be created correctly.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: not sure if it might help [SQL Server Export to Excel
using bcp/sqlcmd Utilities and CSV Files](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm)

Comment: @bummi I'm doing this for a client, and unfortunately the requirement is an `Excel` file. I did bump into the link you shared during my online search, but unfortunately I can't use it.

Comment: @bummi Although, just changing the extension of the file from `.xls` to `.csv` does not generate the above mentioned error when opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

Export the data to a CSV file then import it into Excel and save it as an XLS. You could also create a simple SSIS package using the Import/Export wizard to save the query results into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have SSIS installed on the machine. Is there no way we can do this just with SQL Server? I've seen that it is possible with SSIS.